# How to change format of table in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate the following table as a output in R shiny:

```
data <- matrix(c(67,543940,85),ncol = 1,byrow = T)
colnames(data) <- "France"
rownames(data) <- c("Population (m)", "Size (km)", "No. of cities")
summary <- as.table(data)
output$table <- renderTable(summary)
```

However the data is outputted in the following format:

| Var1 | Var2 | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Population (m) | France | 67 |
| Size (km) | France | 543940 |
| No. of cities | France | 85 |

Instead I want it the table to be displayed as:

|  | France |
| --- | --- |
| **Population (m)** | 67 |
| **Size (km)** | 543940 |
| **No. of cities** | 85 |

How would I do this in R shiny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `as.table()`  function, as this seems to create the problem. To show rownames set the rownames arg to TRUE :

`renderTable(data,rownames = TRUE)`

#### Complete code:

##### server:

```
library(shiny)
## Server:
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- matrix(c(67,543940,85),ncol = 1,byrow = T)
  colnames(data) <- "France"
  rownames(data) <- c("Population (m)", "Size (km)", "No. of cities")
  # this line is not needed and causes the "error"
  # summary <- as.table(data)
  output$table <- renderTable(data,rownames = TRUE)
  

})
```

##### ui:

```
## UI:

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
           tableOutput('table')
    )
  )
)
```

this gives you your desired result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using library(gt) https://gt.rstudio.com/index.html

```
library(gt)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
#############################################
#load your data here 

data <- data.frame(Var1 =  c("Population (m)", "Size (km)", "No. of cities"), 
                   Var2 = rep('France', 3), 
                   Freq = c(67, 543940, 85))
dataLong <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = Freq, 
               names_to = ".value")

  

#############################################
# Define UI for application 
#############################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  "My Shiny App", 
  gt_output('table')
)
#############################################
# Define server logic 
#############################################
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- render_gt(
    
    gt(dataLong) %>% 
      tab_spanner(label = unique(dataLong$Var2), 
                  columns = Freq) %>% 
      cols_hide(Var2) %>% 
      cols_label(Var1 = '', 
                 Freq = ' ')
  )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: sample table]